# DependencyProperty in UserControl doesn't get updated from binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, user-controls

Here is the reproduction of my problem:

- Create a WPF Application
- Add a new UserControl to the project
- Replace its content with the following

---

```
<UserControl 
  x:Class="UserControl1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText}"/>
</UserControl>
```

---

```
Public Class UserControl1
  Public Property MyText As String
    Get
      Return GetValue(MyTextProperty)
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
      SetValue(MyTextProperty, value)
    End Set
  End Property
  Public Shared ReadOnly MyTextProperty As DependencyProperty =
   DependencyProperty.Register("MyText", GetType(String), GetType(UserControl1))
End Class
```

- Replace the following in the MainWindow.xaml file:

---

```
<Window 
  x:Class="MainWindow"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:src="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
  Title="MainWindow"
  DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
  <StackPanel >    
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Title, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    <src:UserControl1 MyText="{Binding Title}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

As you can see, the UserControl1.MyText property doesn't get updated when the MainWindow.Title changes.

What am I missing? I want the user control to be connected to the parent property, is there a xamly way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, when I recreate the app (I'm using C#, so I don't think this will make any difference), I notice in my output the binding is failing because UserControl does not have a Title property.

Add `ElementName=this` to your `UserControl1` binding. And set the Name property on the Window to this and that should fix it.

Something like this:

```
<src:UserControl1 MyText="{Binding Title, ElementName=this}" />
```

The binding works for me when I do that. Hope that helps!

Comment: Btw, what's better to use, `ElementName=Me` or `RelativeSource={{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type src:MainWindow}}`?
What costs more performance?

Comment: For me, it depends on the situation I'm in when I pick one way over the other. I usually just use RelativeSource in my templates and styles. As far as cost in performance? I don't  know. That's a good question I'd like to know the answer for. :)